# PolyMorphic class/Polymorphism/Inner Class -Getting error message

Tags: java, polymorphism, inner-classes

```
public class PolyMorphic {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PolyMorphic.printNumber(new IntNumber(1));
    PolyMorphic.printNumber(new DoubleNumber(4.54));

}

public static void printNumber(MyNumber N) {
    N.print(N);
    System.out.println();
}

public abstract class MyNumber{
    abstract void print(MyNumber N);
}

public class IntNumber extends MyNumber{
    int x;

    IntNumber(){
        x = 3;
    }

    IntNumber(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }


    void print(MyNumber N) {
        double temp = (double)x;
        System.out.printf("%.2f",temp);

    }
}


public class DoubleNumber extends MyNumber{
    double x;

    DoubleNumber(){
        x = 3.23;
    }

    DoubleNumber(double x){
        this.x = x;
    }


    void print(MyNumber N) {
        double temp = x;
        System.out.printf("%.2f",temp);

    }
}

 }
```

So I am trying to create a method in the `PolyMorphic` class named `printNumber` which is `polymorphic` and can print(to the console) either an intNumber with two decimal places to the right or a `DoubleNumber` with three decimal places to the right.  Such as `PolyMorphic.printNumber(new IntNumber(1));`

My Problem is this:

On the Lines:

```
PolyMorphic.printNumber(new IntNUmber(1));
PolyMorphic.printNumber(new DoubleNumber(4.54));
```

This is the error message:

> " No enclosing instance of type PolyMorphic is accessible. Must
>   qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type PolyMorphic
>   (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of PolyMorphic)."

It gives me it for both instances and I am confused to as why It is not working.  IF someone could just point me in the right direction I would be really appreciative.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1):

Your inner classes require an instance of your `PolymorphicClass` because of the way you declared them. However, in your case, you don't need this, so you can mark your inner classes as `static`:

```
public static class IntNumber
```

and

```
public static class DoubleNumber
```

This is a Java design feature.

One other solution would be to operate on an instance of `PolymorphicClass`:

```
Polymorphic p = new Polymorphic();
p.printNumber(new IntNumber(1));
p.printNumber(new DoubleNumber(4.54));
```

EDIT:

You also need:

```
public static abstract class MyNumber
```

Comment: Sorry, New to the website and was just anxious about getting a solution.  I appreciate your help, and your timely answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't nest your MyNumber class and its daughters inside of Polymorphic.

Nesting classes like that is only appropriate when the nested class (`MyNumber`, `IntNumber`, `DoubleNumber`) is part of the implementation of the enclosing class (`Polymorphic`).  In your case, the only relationship between the two classes is that Polymorphic is calling methods on the Number classes.

By the way, the compiler has already told you one solution to your problem, if you would take the trouble to read and understand what it said.  Be grateful, for few compilers are as obliging.

Edit - why is anyone downvoting a reply that is both correct and adds additional information to that provided by other answers?

Comment: It has to be done this way, the professor specifically wants it this way, and I know it tells me what to do but I can't get it to work, I've been up for two days finishing other finals and this is the last thing giving me trouble and it really shouldn't be.

Comment: Seriously though, keeping the classes nested but declaring them static, as the other posters suggested, will achieve a working solution - but is less good design.